# Why specializing a template in source file does not cause an error?

Tags: c++, templates, g++, one-definition-rule

While reviewing some code at work, I noticed something that I believe should not compile, but to my surprise, it does.

There is a template function defined in a header file:

```cpp
template <class T>
web::json::value get_key(const web::json::value &json, const utility::string_t &key) {
    return json.has_field(key) ? json.at(key) : web::json::value(T());
}
```

with a specialization in a source file:

```cpp
template <>
web::json::value get_key<utility::string_t>(const web::json::value &json, const utility::string_t &key) {
    return json.has_string_field(key) ? json.at(key) : web::json::value(utility::string_t());
}
```

Edit: The specialization is not declared in the header file.

As far as I can tell, this should result in the compiler emitting two different definitions for `get_key<utility::string_t>`, one for the specialization in the source file, and one whenever the primary template is instantiated, violating ODR.  However, g++ 8.3.1 compiles and links this without any errors.

Can anyone explain me what is going on here?  Am I missing something, and the above code is actually valid, or is this just a sort of undefined behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: ODR is only violated if the source tokens are different. In this case I believe they will be the same.

Comment: If you never use the `utility::string_t` version in other source files, there is no ODR violation, since there is only one definition.

Comment: @RichardCritten You have `has_field` and `has_string_field` so these are differents.

Comment: @Holt good point

Comment: Follow up multiple definitions can be allowed you need to work through the bullet points: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition

Comment: Violations of the ODR do not have to be diagnosed, and often cannot. So, yes, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

There is no violation of the ODR. Only the specialization should be declared and  visible before the first using of the function template when such a specialization is required.

Comment: It does not cause any error with gcc even if you do not declare the specialization... I don't know if it's a standard behavior or not.

Comment: @Holt Do you mean that the specialization was declared after calling the specialization?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I mean that the specialisation is not even declared when I call it (only the template defined). The specialisation is defined in a different source file. When looking at the assembly, the function is defined in both assembly file, but when compiling and linking, everything goes well and the specialisation is called from the main file.

Comment: @Holt If a specialization is called but not yet declared (declared after the call) then the program is ill-formed. The compiler is allowed not to issue an error.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow In this case the specialization is not declared anywhere except where it is defined, and inspecting the files with `objdump` show that different object code is emitted in the object file corresponding to the source file, and in object files corresponding to the other source files that include the header.